# Stata reshape long to wide

Tags: loops, stata, stata-macros

I'm working with this type of data set in Stata:

| Year | Country | Investment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | US | Bonds Total | 8% |
| 2000 | US | Bonds Private | 50% |
| 2000 | US | Equity Total | 10% |
| 2000 | US | Bonds Public | 50% |
| 2000 | US | Equity listed | 30% |
| 2000 | US | Equity Unlisted | 70% |
| 2000 | FR | Bonds Total | 5% |
| 2000 | FR | Bonds Private | 40% |
| 2000 | FR | Bonds Public | 60% |
| 2001 | US | Bonds Private | 70% |

My issue is that "Bonds Private" and "Bonds Public" are subcategories of "Bonds Total". For my analysis, I would need to have those data in the same line as their respective category.

Thus, I'm trying to achieve this:

| Year | Country | Bonds Total | Bonds Private | Bonds Public | Equity Total | Equity Listed | Equity Unlisted | Real Estate | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | US | 8% | 50% | 50% | 10% | 30% | 70% | 5% | ... |
| 2000 | FR | 5% | 60% | 40% | 12% | 10% | 90% | 8% | ... |
| 2000 | DE | 6% | 40% | 60% | 15% | 10% | 90% | 10% | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2019 | CA | 5% | 60% | 40% | 10% | 30% | 70% | 10% | ... |

I already tried to achieve this by using the function `reshape` but I could not achieve the same result. Here is what I have tried :

```
by Year Country, sort: gen newid = _n    
reshape wide investment, i(year) j(newid)
```

I'm receiving the following error message:

```
values of variable newid not unique within year
```

Comment: Please study the Stata tag wiki and present a data example as code using `dataex`. Alternatively look directly at `help dataex`    We can't comment on code you don't show (although I suspect you don't need any loops here any way).

Comment: Check out the 'reshape' command in Stata. You are trying to transform 'long' data to 'wide' data.

Comment: Hi all, thank you both for your comments! Indeed, it looks like the answer is "reshape" however I was not able to achieve the result I wanted (see updated question).

Comment: The error message is informative. Your observations are identified by country and year. Your code implies that you have `year` and `Year` so watch outl

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a reproducible example I'll try to guess:

```
reshape wide value, i(year country) j(investment) string
```

Use the `string` option in order to allow for string observations ("Bonds total" etc..) to be used as variable names.

Rename the variables accordingly afterwards.